# How do I reverse Hash.inspect or Array.inspect? (aka .to_s) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, serialization, hash, inspect

I accidentally saved a Ruby hash to string in Ruby 1.9 by calling `my_hash.to_s` which is equal to `my_hash.inspect`. This gave me a string like this:

```
'{"foo"=>{"bar"=>"baz", "qux"=>"quux"}'
```

I now want to revert this back into a hash. How is this done?

I'm not looking for an explanation on other serialisation techniques, I know them. I just need a way to revert this back so I can save it the right way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The fastest answer is: `eval`.

```
my_hash = eval(my_str_hash)
```

Comment: So, if you like my answer, you must accept it by clicking on the "√" :)

Comment: WARNING: never, NEVER eval untrusted input.

Answer (score 6):

eval it.

Of course that's not safe for arbitrary input but you said you know about serialization issues. It won't work for collections containing recursive references or other objects for which eval(x.inspect) != x.